# Does it makes sense to use cubit/bloc if I already have a repository pattern structure created?

Tags: flutter, repository, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I already have a base structure that I have used for some projects where I define the next in the top of the widget tree.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<DataRepository>(
        create: (_) => DataRepository(
              apiService: APIService(ApiBak()),
              dataCacheService: DataCacheService(
                sharedPreferences: widget.sharedPreferences,
              ),
            ),
        child: LayoutBuilder( .....
...
```

Meaning I have access to my repository where I have my APIService to make any http requests and my cacheService if needed. In some projects i defined inside the repository a local database too.
So my question is simple, does it make sense to use bloc/cubit pattern or any other state managment process if I already have this and setState ?
And if so, what´s the best way to add it to what I already have ?
Thanks